# Changing unevenly spaced time data into evenly spaced hourly in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have some weather data that comes in unevenly spaced, and I would like to grab the simple hourly values. I need hourly so I can join this data up with a separate data.frame

Example of the weather data:

```
> weather_df
A tibble: 10 × 3
              datetime temperature temperature_dewpoint
                <dttm>       <dbl>                <dbl>
1  2011-01-01 00:00:00           4                   -1
2  2011-01-01 00:20:00           3                   -1
3  2011-01-01 00:40:00           3                   -1
4  2011-01-01 01:00:00           2                   -1
5  2011-01-01 01:20:00           2                    0
6  2011-01-01 01:45:00           2                    0
7  2011-01-01 02:05:00           1                   -1
8  2011-01-01 02:25:00           2                    0
9  2011-01-01 02:45:00           2                   -1
10 2011-01-01 03:10:00           2                    0
```

I would like to only have hourly data, but as you can see observations don't always fall on the hour mark. I've tried rounding but then I have multiple observations with the same time.

```
weather_df$datetime_rounded <- as.POSIXct(round(weather_df$datetime, units = c("hours")))

weather_df
# A tibble: 10 × 4
              datetime temperature temperature_dewpoint    datetime_rounded
            <dttm>       <dbl>                <dbl>              <dttm>
1  2011-01-01 00:00:00           4                   -1 2011-01-01 00:00:00
2  2011-01-01 00:20:00           3                   -1 2011-01-01 00:00:00
3  2011-01-01 00:40:00           3                   -1 2011-01-01 01:00:00
4  2011-01-01 01:00:00           2                   -1 2011-01-01 01:00:00
5  2011-01-01 01:20:00           2                    0 2011-01-01 01:00:00
6  2011-01-01 01:45:00           2                    0 2011-01-01 02:00:00
7  2011-01-01 02:05:00           1                   -1 2011-01-01 02:00:00
8  2011-01-01 02:25:00           2                    0 2011-01-01 02:00:00
9  2011-01-01 02:45:00           2                   -1 2011-01-01 03:00:00
10 2011-01-01 03:10:00           2                    0 2011-01-01 03:00:00
```

I can't determine easily which observation to keep without computing the difference of `datetime` from `datetimerounded`. There must be a more elegant way to do this. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my non-elegant solution.

I calculated the absolute distance between `datetime` and `datetime_rounded`

```
weather_df$time_dist <- abs(weather_df$datetime - weather_df$datetimerounded)
```

Then I sorted by the distance

```
weather_df <- weather_df[order(weather_df$time_dist),]
```

The removed duplicates of the rounded column. Since its sorted it keeps the observation closest to the round hour.

```
weather_df <- weather_df [!duplicated(weather_df$datetimerounded),]
```

Then sorted back by the time

```
weather_df <-  weather_df [order(weather_df$datetimerounded),]
```

Sure there has to be a better way to do this. I'm not very familiar yet with working with time series in R.